# Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and $|H|=10$. If $a$ belongs to $G$ and $a^6$ belongs to $H$, then what are the possibilities for $|a|$?

Tags: group-theory

I understand that since $a^6$ belongs to $H$, then $a^{60}=e$. But I am not sure what are the possibilities for the order of $a$?

Comment: $a^{60} = e$ puts some large restraints on the possibilities for $|a|$. Can you tell what those are? For instance, is it possible that $|a| = 7$?

Comment: See Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Lagrange’s theorem is only valid for finite groups. Here G may not be finite.

Answer (score 5):

We have seen already that the order of $a$ must divide 60. In fact all divisors of 60 are possible orders of $a$.

To see this let $G=\langle x \rangle$ be cyclic of order 60 and $H=\langle x^6\rangle$. Then all powers $a$ of $x$ satisfy $a^6\in H$. Also for any divisor $k$ of 60, $x^{60/k}$ has order $k$.

Comment: if ${|H|=10,  a^6 \in H}$, then it doesn't mean ${|G|=60}$, we only know that order of ${a^6}$ should divide ${|H|=10}$, so ${|a^6|}$ can be 1,2,5,10.  check the cyclic group of order 30, where ${|<a^3>|=10}$  Could you please explain, how did we decide to take G of order 60 and not G of order 30

Comment: I know that this doesn't mean that $|G|=60$ - I never said it did. I was constructing examples to show that all divisors of $60$ are possible as orders of $h$. So it is up to me to choose whatever $G$ I like, provided that it works. I never claimed that other examples are not possible.  But one advantage of my choice is that you can use the same $G$ for all possible orders of $h$.

Answer (score 2):

$a^{6}\in H$ and $|H|=10\implies(a^6)^{10}=a^{60}=e\implies |a|\ \big|\ 60$. So any possible value of $|a|$ must be a divisor of $60$

Comment: You also need to decide whether all divisors of $60$ are possibilities - in fact they are.

Comment: Tell me more on this

Comment: $a^6\in H\implies |a^6|\ \big| \ 10\implies |a^6|=1,2,5\ or\ 10$. so now we can derive what posible values of $|a|$ from the possible values of $|a^6|$.

Answer (score 0):

We do indeed get $a^{60}=e$.  Thus $\vert a\vert\mid60$.

So, the order of $a$ is at most $60$.

But it could be less.  It is easy to see that the cyclic group $C_{60}$ provides an example where there are such elements $a$ with any given order $d$ dividing $60$.

How about an example of an infinite group that realizes all these possibilities?  Take $G$ to be the direct sum of all $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.  Then $G$ has elements of all orders $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.  In particular,  it has a subgroup isomorphic to $C_{60}$.